# How to make spawn canvas with render camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, assign

UNITY 2D C#

I have a Canvas object.

My Canvas is image (ARROW) that indicates target (STAR).

When a STAR hit the PLAYER,it is destroyed.

Unfortunately, I can not turn off the ARROW and (when STAR respawn) turn on it again, because after appearing ARROW indicates the previous target.

That's why I must to destroy the canvas.

I added a script to the STAR :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyTest : MonoBehaviour {


    public SpawnStar other;

    public GameObject Spawner;
    public GameObject ToDestroy;

    void Awake (){
        GameObject Spawner = GameObject.Find ("Spawner");
        other = Spawner.GetComponent<SpawnStar>();

    }


        void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll){


    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player") {

            Destroy (gameObject);
            Debug.Log("DestroyedStar");
            GameObject ToDestroy = GameObject.Find ("Window_QuestPointer");
            Destroy (ToDestroy);

            Debug.Log("DestroyedOptionOne");
            other.Start ();
        }
    }
}
```

I added a script to the CANVAS:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using CodeMonkey.Utils;


public class Window_QuestPointer : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Camera uiCamera;

public SpawnStar other;

public GameObject Spawner;

private Vector3 targetPosition;
private RectTransform pointerRectTransform;



void Awake (){
    GameObject Spawner = GameObject.Find ("Spawner");
    other = Spawner.GetComponent<SpawnStar>();
    other.Start ();

}

private void Start ()
{
    targetPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("Star").transform.position;
    pointerRectTransform = transform.Find ("Pointer").GetComponent<RectTransform> ();



}
private void Update (){
    Vector3 toPosition = targetPosition;
    Vector3 fromPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
    fromPosition.z = 0f;
    Vector3 dir = (toPosition - fromPosition).normalized;
    float angle = UtilsClass.GetAngleFromVectorFloat(dir);
    pointerRectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, angle);

    float borderSize = 40f;

    Vector3 targetPositionScreenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (targetPosition);
    bool isOffscreen = targetPositionScreenPoint.x <= borderSize || targetPositionScreenPoint.x >= Screen.width - borderSize || targetPositionScreenPoint.y <= borderSize || targetPositionScreenPoint.y >= Screen.height - borderSize;
    Debug.Log (isOffscreen + " " + targetPositionScreenPoint);

    if(isOffscreen){
        Vector3 cappedTargetScreenPosition = targetPositionScreenPoint;
        cappedTargetScreenPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp (cappedTargetScreenPosition.x, borderSize, Screen.width - borderSize);
        cappedTargetScreenPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp (cappedTargetScreenPosition.y, borderSize, Screen.height - borderSize);

        Vector3 pointerWorldPosition = uiCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint (cappedTargetScreenPosition);
        pointerRectTransform.position = pointerWorldPosition;
        pointerRectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3 (pointerRectTransform.localPosition.x, pointerRectTransform.localPosition.y, 0f);

    }
    else{
        Vector3 pointerWorldPosition = uiCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint (targetPositionScreenPoint);
        pointerRectTransform.position = pointerWorldPosition;
        pointerRectTransform.localPosition = new Vector3 (pointerRectTransform.localPosition.x, pointerRectTransform.localPosition.y, 0f);

    }
}
```

}

I added a script to the SPAWNER object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnStar : MonoBehaviour {



    private int waveNumber = 0;
    public int enemiesAmount = 0;
    public GameObject star;
public GameObject option;
    public Camera cam;
public GameObject objectToEnable;


    // Use this for initialization
    public void Start () {


    StartCoroutine (StarEnable());
        cam = Camera.main;
        enemiesAmount = 0;


    objectToEnable.SetActive (false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
public IEnumerator StarEnable () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10f);
        float height = cam.orthographicSize + 1; // now they spawn just outside
        float width = cam.orthographicSize * cam.aspect + 1;
        if (enemiesAmount==0) {

                Instantiate(star, new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x + Random.Range(-width, width),3,cam.transform.position.z+height+Random.Range(10,30)),Quaternion.identity);
                enemiesAmount++;

        Instantiate (option, transform.position, transform.rotation);


        objectToEnable.SetActive (true);

            }

        }
    }
```

In addition, the ARROW must respawn in the screen and the STAR off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't destroy a canvas or any GameObject during runtime, answering your question, when you Instantiate the canvas prefab, set the renderer camera with 
`canvas.worldCamera`, but you can, instead of destroying your canvas, create a container inside of it put all the GameObjects inside of this GameObject container, and activate and deactivate it when needed.

Comment: in unity, there's the OnEnable and OnDisable call, that's called every time that an object is Enabled or Disabled, when you start the game, unity calls the OnEnable for each game Object in your scene, you can try to update your target when your object is toggled, and disable it instead of destroying it.

Comment: Ok, but how I can update new coordinates of my object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one camera U can attach simple script which finds Canvas commonent and attach camera to it in Start() for example:

```
public class AttachCamera: MonoBehavour
{
  private void Start()
  {
    gameObject.GetComponent<Canvas>().worldCamera = Camera.main;
  }
}
```

If there are more than one camera U have to remember attached camera and set it mannualy after Canvas was spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your code that is responsible for destroying the Canvas?

I would use another GameObject that handles this gameplay logic.

First, I would use cameraObj.SetActive(false); to disable the camera, and not destroy it.  Destroying and Creating objects can cause memory issues sometimes, and it's just not good practice unless absolutely necessary.

Then, use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [WaitForSeconds()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) or something to that effect to wait, and then call cameraObj.SetActive(true) to re-enable your Camera's main GameObject.